# Number of nodes in a B tree

Tags: data-structures, b-tree

In a B tree with minimum degree t, each non leaf node other than root has at least t children and at most 2*t children. Suppose that the keys {1,2,3...,n} are inserted into an empty B tree with minimum degree 2 in the sequence 1,2,3.....,n. How many nodes does the final B tree have?

From what I have understood, I feel it would be n/t since minimum number of keys each node can have is k, and the total number of keys is n. Am I correct?? If not Tell me where am I going wrong and how should I do this?

Comment: Already answered @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26238014/number-of-nodes-in-a-b-tree/27660157#27660157

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is `(n-2)*log(n-2)` with `t=2`

Answer (score 0):

We know that every node except the root must have at least t−1=1 keys, and at most 2t−1=3 keys. The final tree can have at most n−1 nodes when n≥2. Unless n=1 there cannot ever be n nodes since we only ever insert a key into a non-empty node, so there will always be at least one node with 2 keys. Next observe that we will never have more than one key in a node which is not a right spine of our B-tree. This is because every key we insert is larger than all keys stored in the tree, so it will be inserted into the right spine of the tree. The fewest possible number of nodes occurs when every node except the deepest node in the right spine has 2 keys and the deepest node in the right spline has 3 keys. So at height 1, 1 nodes, at height 2, 3 nodes, …, at level h, 2h−1 nodes. In this case, n =∑*(i=1)^h▒2^i  +1=2h+1−1 where h is the height of the B-tree, and the number of nodes in B-Tree is #nodes = ∑*(i=1)^h▒〖(2^i-1)〗 = 2h+1−2−h = n−lg(n+1). So for any n, the final B-Tree must have n−⌊lg(n+1)⌋≤#nodes≤n−1 (if n≥2).